# Function with 2 variables within a domain

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have the following problem.

Find the maximum and minimum of the following function:

$$x^2 + y^2 - 4x - 2y +4$$

within the range $$x^2 + y^2 ≤ 16$$

I have ofcourse attempted this question myself. I have managed to find the minimum value. I did this by taking the derivative of the function two times, once with respect to x and once with respect to y. This gave me the point (2,1) and after substituting it back in the function gave the minimum value of -1.

Now i am trying to calculate the maximum value of the maximum value of the function which i think we can find by looking at the boundary values, x^2 + y^2 ≤ 16.

I have tried two things and still get the incorrect answer.

Attempt 1:

Substituting $$x = 4cost$$, $$y = 4sint$$.

$$16cos^2(t) + 16sin^2(t) - 4*4cost(t) - 2*4sin(t) + 4$$

$$16(cos^2(t) + sin^2(t)) - 16cos(t) - 8 sin(t) + 4$$

$$16 - 16cos(t) - 8sin(t) + 4$$

$$20 - 16cos(t) - 8sin(t)$$

By looking at the last line here, we can see that the maximum is when t = pi. This will cos(t) = -1 and sin(t) = 0

20 - 16cos(t) - 8sin(t) = 20 + 16 - 0 = 36. However 36 is incorrect and i dont understand why.

Attempt 2:

$$x^2 + y^2 ≤ 16$$

$$x^2 + y^2 = 16$$

$$y = sqrt(16-x^2)$$

Substituting this into the original equation gives:

$$x^2 + (16-x^2) - 4x - 2sqrt(16-x^2) +4$$

$$20 - 2sqrt(16-x^2) - 4x$$

By looking at this equation we can see that the maximum value is when 2sqrt(16-x^2) is 0. This happens when x = 4.

$$20 - 2sqrt(16-(4)^2) -4(4)$$

$$20 - 0 - 16 = 4$$

4 is also incorrect.

Can anyone help me with this question. I would also like to understand why I cant solve the question in the way i have attempted.

Thank you for your time. Please tell me if something was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't leave geometric intuition by the wayside.** After completing the squares to get
$$f(x,y)=(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2-1$$
we see that the value of $f(x,y)$ is simply the squared distance from $(x,y)$ to $(2,1)$, minus one.

To find the maximum, we must therefore look for the point in your domain that is *farthest from* $(2,1)$. That's the one on the opposite end of the diameter through $(2,1)$, and its distance from $(2,1)$ is
$$ 4 + \sqrt{2^2+1^2} $$
The square of this distance is
$$ 16 + 5 + 8\sqrt5 $$
so the maximum function value is
$$ 20 + 8\sqrt5 $$

---

In your attempt 1, you're wrong when you claim that the maximum of $20-16\cos t-8\sin t$ is at $t=\pi$. Consider that at that point the derivative of the cosine is $0$, so a small change in $t$ does not affect that term -- the derivative of the sine is $-1$, so a $t$ slightly larger than $\pi$ will lead to a higher value for the function. So we *didn't* have a maximum at $t=\pi$.

In your attempt 2, I don't get at all how you conclude that " the maximum value is when $2\sqrt{16-x^2}$ is $0$".

Answer (score 0):

Note that your $f(x,y)$ is equal to $$f(x,y)=(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2-1$$ and from here we get
$$f_{min}=-1$$ for $y=2,x=1$

Comment: That is interesting, I did not see that at first. Do you think it could be used to find the maximum? Im trying to learn how to analyse the boundry values, maybe they could used here?

Comment: I think for the Maximum you will Need derivatives

Comment: Well i took the partial derivatives and set them to zero. It gave me the coordinates for the minimum value.

Comment: Ok, then use the Lagrange Multiplier method: $$F(x,y,\lambda)=x^2+y^2-4x-2y+4+\lambda(x^2+y^2-16)$$

Comment: I am not familiar with that type of solution.

Comment: One Moment, i will send you a link.

Comment: This is the Link: http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_LAGRANGE_METHOD.PDF